# Material UI - Checkbox Label is Missing

Tags: material-design, material-ui

I'm learning `Material UI` and I'm trying to display an checkbox with a label.  Following the samples in the online [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox), I'm rendering a checkbox, but no label.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 return (
        <div className="entryForm" >
            <div style={{width:'100%'}}>
                <h3 style={ {display:'inline-block' } }>
                    User Details
                </h3>
                <span style={{float:'right'}}>
                    <Checkbox
                        label="Active"
                        labelPosition="left"
                    />
                </span>
            </div>...
```

Comment: The code you have works for me (displays both a checkbox and the label "Active"). Is there some other code that could help reproduce this problem?

Comment: As a side note, if you're just starting out with material-ui, you should [use v1 instead of v0](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui#should-i-start-with-v1-beta).

Comment: @JulesDupont...I think I'm using v1 - Tom's answer fixed my problem.  Thanks

Comment: Oh alright - you linked to the v0 doc site so I assumed you were using v0. For your future reference, the v1 doc site is at [here](https://material-ui-next.com/).

Comment: @JulesDupont...so, that was my problem - old docs!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it depends on the MUI version you are using.
If you're using version 1.0 and above you should use FormControlLabel:

```
import {FormControlLabel} from 'material-ui/Form';

<FormControlLabel
control={
    <Checkbox
        name="SomeName"
        value="SomeValue"
    />
}
label="MyLabel"/>
```

More in the documentation:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/

Answer (score 3):

FormControlLabel would be the way to go, here is what it looks like with the updated import v4.11.1

```
import { FormControlLabel } from '@material-ui/core';

<FormControlLabel
control={
    <Checkbox
        name="SomeName"
        value="SomeValue"
    />
}
label="MyLabel"/>
```